# Props are not passing to the test cases

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a simple component, but not able to pass props for my test cases, It was working fine without  - withRouter. what could be the reason

**Component**

```
const Plugins = ({pluginsData, history}) => {

    return (
        <ul className="plugin-list">
            <li
                appearance="subtle"
                weight="medium"
                className="item"
                onClick={() => history.push(`/list/plugins`)}>Plugins</li>
                {  pluginsData.length
                ? pluginsData.map((item, index) => <li className="up-coming-text" key={index}>{item.plugin}</li>)
                : " No Data" }
        </ul>
    )
}
```

export default withRouter(Plugins)

**plugin.test.js**

```
  const pluginsData= [
        {
            "plugin": "Apps (Coming soon)"
        }
    ]

   
const wrapper = shallow(<Plugins pluginsData={pluginsData}/>);

describe('test home page', () => {

    it('should render home page successfully', () => {
        expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
    });

    it('renders correct text in item', () => {
        expect(wrapper.find('.up-coming-text').get(0).props.children).toEqual('Apps (Coming soon)');
    });

    it('renders pluginsData length', () => {
        expect(wrapper.find('.up-coming-text')).toBeDefined();
        expect(wrapper.find('.up-coming-text').length).toEqual(pluginsData.length);
    });

});
```

**Error**

ΓùÅ test home page ΓÇ║ renders pluginsData length

```
expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

Expected: 1
Received: 0

  28 |     it('renders pluginsData length', () => {
  29 |         expect(wrapper.find('.up-coming-text')).toBeDefined();
> 30 |         expect(wrapper.find('.up-coming-text').length).toEqual(pluginsData.length);
     |                                                        ^
  31 |     });
  32 |
  33 | });

  at Object.<anonymous> (ui/src/routes/Explorer/Plugins/plugins.test.js:30:56)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't pass the `pluginsData` props correctly. It should be:

```js
const wrapper = shallow(<Plugins pluginsData={pluginsData}/>);
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-v26-codelab/tree/main/examples/66694262

Comment: @AtulVerma I updated my answer with an example

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Component.WrappedComponent](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/b529499efcb906c814b9a3a68e2b4292a15b09c8/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md#componentwrappedcomponent) to test the component in isolation.

From the [docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/b529499efcb906c814b9a3a68e2b4292a15b09c8/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md#componentwrappedcomponent),

> The wrapped component is exposed as the static property `WrappedComponent` on the returned component, which can be used for testing the component in isolation, among other things.

```
shallow(<Plugins.WrappedComponent pluginsData={pluginsData}/>)
```